# How to disable the TO address on compose email UI using MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, email, xamarin.ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I need to disable the **TO address** on compose mail UI. Because i used static email address. Also i don't want **CC/Bcc address**. How to remove **CC/Bcc address** on compose mail UI? I'm using `MFMailComposeViewController` for sending email.

I'm using MonoTouch. How to achieve this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that, and there's a good reason.
Apple's approach to UI design is to make sure user is always in control.

If you present user with an email form, you should be prepared she might want to cancel and save it as a draft for later, add her other email address to CC, or even change To address if she really wants to.

The [documentation for `MFMailComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) explicitly states:

> The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content.

To sum up, if you don't want user to be in control of target address, perhaps you should consider sending an email bypassing the `MFMailComposeViewController` UI.